# sum of the series: $\cos^3 \alpha +\cos^3 {3\alpha} + \cos^3 {5\alpha}+....+\cos^3 {(2n-1)\alpha}$.

Tags: trigonometry, summation, telescopic-series

> **Question**: Find the sum of the series:
>   $$\cos^3 \alpha +\cos^3 {3\alpha} + \cos^3 {5\alpha}+\ldots+\cos^3 {(2n-1)\alpha}$$

*The book from which this question was taken says that the answer is $$\dfrac{3\sin{n\alpha}\cos{n\alpha}}{4\sin\alpha}+\dfrac{\sin{3n\alpha}\cos{3n\alpha}}{4\sin{3\alpha}}.$$*

My attempt to solve this question:
$$\text{Let S be the trigonometric series,}$$
$$\cos {3\theta} = 4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta \implies 4\cos^3 \theta=\cos{3\theta}+3\cos\theta$$
Applying formula on $\cos^3\theta$,
$$4S = 3\cos\alpha + \cos3\alpha +3\cos3\alpha + \cos9\alpha+\ldots+3\cos{(2n-1)\alpha}+\cos{(6n-3)\alpha}$$
$$4S= 3(\cos \alpha + \cos 3\alpha+\cos5\alpha+\ldots)+(\cos3\alpha + \cos9\alpha+\ldots)$$
Applying the summation of cosine formula,
$$4S= 3\frac{\sin{n\alpha}}{\sin\alpha}\cdot\cos{(\alpha+(n-1)\alpha)}+?$$

So my problem is I don't know how to apply the formula for the second series (denoted by '?') for a fixed number of terms $n$ or should I treat it as a general and separate series.

To clarify my doubt again, what I am asking is that would the $(2n-1)$ affect the formula for the second series (denoted by '?').

*My working here looks most probably correct but if there is any mistake please correct it.*

Comment: Unfortunately, your question needs an upvoted or accepted answer in order to be flagged as a duplicate. What you can do is flag the question for moderator attention to close this one down.